# jQuery Validate error event

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validate plugin to validate my form and need a way to detect when form field is returned as invalid. I want to push some more HTML to form field when it returns invalid. I am able to push success tickmark when field returns as valid with "success:" method, but I am somehow not able to find the correct method to detect when field is invalid.

Comment: Although I understood your question, you should still be showing us your relevant code so that future readers with similar problems are also helped.

Comment: We have no idea what you're trying to do on the invalid event... are you trying to remove the success tickmark?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to push some more HTML to form field when it returns invalid.

Use [the `highlight` and `unhighlight` functions](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#highlight).  These are normally used to toggle the `error` and `valid` classes on the elements.  As long as you keep the default part of the function in place, you can add your custom code to these.

> not able to find the correct method to detect when field is invalid.

`highlight` fires when field is invalid.

```js
// FIRES WHEN INVALID
highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    if (element.type === "radio") {
        this.findByName(element.name).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    } else {
        $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    }
    // your custom code here - field is INVALID
},
// FIRES WHEN VALID
unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    if (element.type === "radio") {
        this.findByName(element.name).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
    } else {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
    }
    // your custom code here - field is VALID
}
```

Of course, you can also change the default code, but then the classes may not toggle properly.  Leverage the `element` argument which represents the form field being validated.

> I am able to push success tickmark when field returns as valid with "success:" method

Since you'll be using `highlight` for "invalid", you should use `unhighlight` instead of `success` when it's "valid". (You can still keep `success` for tickmark with this).

Side-note: a `success` tickmark is shown within the regular error `label` object so there is normally no need to use an error event to remove this... it's automatically removed whenever there is a new error.